# Multiple ajax requests from a PHP function result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I have the following code that returns multiple items as follows:
PHP function - the return form the while statement: This return results on multiple lines with the same id (view_contact_activity) but different values.

```
    echo "
    <ul class=\"feeds\">
        <li>
            <a id=\"view_contact_activity\" href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
          <div class=\"id\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"this_activity_id\" value=\"$activity_id\"></div>
            <div class=\"col1\">


        <div class=\"cont\">
                <div class=\"cont-col1\">
                    <div class=\"label label-sm label-success\">
                        <i class=\"$activity_type_icon\"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=\"cont-col2\">
                    <div class=\"desc\">
                         $activity_title
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"col2\">
            <div class=\"dueDate\">
                 $activity_due_date
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul> ";
```

The script the triggers the action (calls another function which return JSON array of objects):

```
$(document).on("click", "#view_contact_activity", function () {

        var this_activity_id = $(this).closest('.feeds').find('.id #this_activity_id').val();
    $('#view-contact-activity').modal('show')

    $('#view-contact-activity').on('show.bs.modal', function() { 
        $modal = $(this);
        $.ajax({
           url: '../includes/functions/contact-functions.php',
           data: {view_activity_id:this_activity_id},
           dataType:'json',
           success: function(response){
               // Find the elements in the modal
               $modal.find('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);
               $modal.find('#activity_type').val(response[0].activity_type);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT - Adding JSON result:

```
[{"id":"12","activity_type":"meeting","activity_title":"meeting","activity_details":"ds","activity_status":""}]
```

When I click on ("view_contact_activity) the result comes back as i clicked on the one above or some times no returns in the modal. after few clicks more requests show in firebug but the returned value is not for the clicked one.
Hopefully i made it clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem is multiple ajax requests. One possible solution is to abort the previous request before sending a new one if the previous one is not yet completed.

```
var contactAjax;
$(document).on("click", "#view_contact_activity", function () {
    var this_activity_id = $(this).closest('.feeds').find('.id #this_activity_id').val();
    $('#view-contact-activity').data('activity-id', this_activity_id).modal('show')
});
//use event delegation if #view-contact-activity is created dynamically
$('#view-contact-activity').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    //create a local variable
    var $modal = $(this),
        this_activity_id = $modal.data('activity-id');
    if (contactAjax && $.isFunction(contactAjax.abort)) {
        //abort the previous request
        contactAjax.abort();
    }
    contactAjax = $.ajax({
        url: '../includes/functions/contact-functions.php',
        data: {
            view_activity_id: this_activity_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            // Find the elements in the modal
            $modal.find('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);
            $modal.find('#activity_type').val(response[0].activity_type);
        }
    }).always(function () {
        contactAjax = undefined;
    });
});
```